# tableView is not removing the last deleted cell immediately

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delete-row

I'm having trouble removing the last cell I have tried `tableView.reloadData()` and beginUpdate(), endUpadate(), and all these methods works fine if I have more than one cell, but when I come to deleting the last cell it didn't work and the tableView won't `reloadData` at the same time that I delete the last cell, other cells 2-3-4 no problem, Plus when I close the app everyThing works fine.

im deleting the cells from the firebase store its a document that contains data if concern

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
  if editingStyle == .delete {
    print("Deleted")
    
    
    self.DriverOffers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.DriverOrdersTV.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()
    
    
    
  }else if editingStyle == .insert {
    self.DriverOrdersTV.beginUpdates()
    self.DriverOrdersTV.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    self.DriverOrdersTV.endUpdates()
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add the code for `cellForRow:atIndexPath` to show how you are populating the cells. Plus I would like to see is you are adding any footer as well.

Comment: reloadData should be call on Main UI thread

Comment: @ShauketSheikh even with a breakpoint, I couldn't detect reloading

Comment: Delete `reloadData()`. It's redundant. `deleteRows` does the job. And delete `beginUpdates/endUpdates`. They are redundant, too, because they have no effect.

Comment: @vadian that's right actually but the cell still stuck in my tableView

Comment: And you should **always** use the `tableView` instance which is provided by the method parameter rather than the outlet or other strong reference.

Comment: sadly didn't work

Comment: Then the reason is somewhere else. The code is the usual straightforward way to delete a row.

Comment: @CloudMusic Code is perfect for delete row. But might be some other issue is occurs. Can you please update your question and add all the delegate and data source which was in controller and also second try was please call reload data in main thread.

Comment: @vadian just now I have deleted the document in code, still facing the same issue and this is not good for the user experience to select a cell that doesn't exist, the app will crash and it already did, one thing that I would like to mention is that I have tried to get the count of the array in `didSet{}`, `if DriverOffers.count == 0 {}` it did work but if any element in the get deleted or inserted I have to reload all the data at once or you can say reload all array while having `tableVie.backgoundView = someView` appears and dissappear whith when ever `tableView.reloadData()` gets called

Comment: As you was mentioning *...deleting the cells from the firebase store* you should delete the item in the database first and on (successful) completion update the table view.